# Rails 3 - id passed is ActiveRecord::Relation, how to find object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a conditional edit button, i.e. create if record does not exist, edit otherwise. I have somewhat accomplished this like so:

```
  <% if !appl.hvac_environment.nil? %>
    <%= link_to 'Review', edit_hvac_environment_path(HvacEnvironment.where("appliance_id = ?", :appl), :a => appl) %>
  <% else%>
    <%= link_to 'Review', new_hvac_environment_path(:a => appl)%></td>
  <% end %>
```

appl is the appliance in my form, which has a 'hvac_environment' association. I am passing :a to retrieve the appl id to store in the hvac_env object's field.

My contoller then attempts to find the appropriate record to edit, but cannot find by id in 'edit' method because the id passed is an active record object: Couldn't find HvacEnvironment with id=#ActiveRecord::Relation:0x9fbe8f8>. Why does my form pass this and how can I pass the hvac_env id so I can edit the appropriate object.

This works when there is no record, so im sure the problem is with the second line, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I assume that you have Appliance model that has has_one relationship with HvacEnvironment

In this case this should work

```
 <% if !appl.hvac_environment.nil? %>
  <%= link_to 'Review', edit_hvac_environment_path( appl.hvac_environment, :a => appl) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The ActiveRelation `where` clause converts the parameters directly to SQL, they don't take any of the actual relationships into account, you must use actual database column names and pass in primitive values.

So I'm guessing you need somethings like

```
<%= link_to 'Review', edit_hvac_environment_path(HvacEnvironment.where("appliance_id = ?", appl.id), :a => appl) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You get an `ActiveRecord::Relation` because `where` and friends return an object of this class not the results set, the reason is simple, these methods are chainable and in this way the SQL query is built and executed just one time when you actually access one of the results.

In this case you can simply access the first HvacEnvironment and you'll get the HvacEnvironment object you need:

```
HvacEnvironment.where("appliance_id = ?", :appl).first
```

Comment: Perhaps I went wrong somewhere, as I am new to rails, but I had tried this and got another error. The solution below worked for me. Many thanks.